# VSCode is coloring python code strangely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

For some reason VSCode is coloring my Python code strangely. See screenshots below

[image]

[image: here]

Normally, variables were white. Now they are light blue and hurt to look at. Is there a setting or extension that changes the formatting to these colors? Did the default settings change? How do I make the variables white again?

Here's a screenshot of my whole screen.

[image]

VSCode seems to be having trouble importing libraries. Even common ones like Pandas. The error says:

`Import "numpy" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports`

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your whole VSCode window?

Comment: try to disable `semantic highlighting`

Comment: There has recently been a larger update to Python extension. Could that be the reason?

Comment: `semantic highlighting` was the problem! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer so that it's easier to find in the future.

As @rioV8 suggested this is caused by `semantic highlighting`

For example, this is VSCode without Semantic Highlighting

[image]

And this is with Semantic Highlighting

[image]

To disable it, in your `settings.json` file

set

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "semanticHighlighting": false
}
```